# How to rotate UIImageview anticlock wise

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am using following code to full rotate image for clockwise

```
       - (void) runSpinAnimationOnView:(UIView*)view duration:(CGFloat)duration         rotations:      (CGFloat)rotations repeat:(float)repeat;
  {
   CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
   rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
       rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: rotations * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * rotations * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;
    [view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
    }
```

and Calling it

```
          [self runSpinAnimationOnView:_cycleImage duration:0.1 rotations:M_PI_2 repeat:13];
```

it rotates the image clockwise and locks great , but How can rotate the same image and same animation and duration anti-clockwise.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an anti-clockwise rotation, set `rotationAnimation.toValue` to a *negative* value,
for example

```
rotationAnimation.toValue = @(-2.0*M_PI);
```

for one full anti-clockwise rotation.